# yolov3 is not install on win10

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, yolo

I would like to install yolov3 on a win 10 system and the environments installed are:

```
numpy>=1.18.2
scipy>=1.4.1
wget>=3.2
seaborn>=0.10.0
tensorflow==2.3.1
tensorflow-gpu==2.3.1
opencv-python==4.1.2.30
tqdm==4.43.0
pandas
awscli
urllib3
mss
keras == 1.2.2
Python 3.7.8 win64
pip version 20.2.4
```

Why can't I install yolov3?
There are several errors that appear, such as:
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy

When running pip install yolov3, the system gives me the following errors (there are many more but I exceeded the allowed dimensions):

````
```

 # pip3 install yolov3

Collecting yolov3
  Using cached yolov3-1.7-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 kB)
    Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject
    \pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version markdown>=2.6.8->te
    nsorboard=1.14.0->tensorflow==1.14.0->yolov3) (3.4.0)
    Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
      Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\sc
    ripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sfran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
    \\pip-install-958of2go\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sfran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-958o
    f2go\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
     '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local
    \Temp\pip-wheel-dtwl6u5l'
           cwd: C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy\
      Complete output (238 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\
    pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      blis_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\py
    thonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
    ...
    
      C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution
     option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualst
    udio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      Running setup.py clean for numpy
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\sc
    ripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sfran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
    \\pip-install-958of2go\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sfran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-958o
    f2go\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
     '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
           cwd: C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy
      Complete output (10 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
    
      `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
    
        - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
        - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                            files that aren't checked into the git repo)
    
      Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
    
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
    Failed to build numpy
    Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python, Keras, keras-applications, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, t
    ensorflow, yolov3
      Attempting uninstall: numpy
        Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.4
        Uninstalling numpy-1.19.4:
          Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.19.4
        Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\
    scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sfran\\AppData\\Local\\Te
    mp\\pip-install-958of2go\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sfran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-95
    8of2go\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"
    ', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sfran\AppData\L
    ocal\Temp\pip-record-6o8tmn9q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c
    :\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\include\site\pyt
    hon3.7\numpy'
             cwd: C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy\
        Complete output (243 lines):
        Running from numpy source directory.
    
        Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
        with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
    
          - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                   release)
          - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
    
    
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproject
    \\pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        blis_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\
    pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproje
    ct\\pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intel
    vem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
         C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        "svnversion" non Š riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
         un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
        "svnversion" non Š riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
         un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        F2PY Version 2
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproject
    \\pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproje
    ct\\pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_clapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pyth
    onproject\\pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\
    pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\p
    ythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_3_10_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\
    pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\p
    ythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pyth
    onproject\pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\p
    ythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonpr
    oject\pythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\sfran\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\pythonproject\pythonproject\p
    ythonproject\testvhsn\venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\sfran\\pycharmprojects\\pythonproject\\pythonproject\\pythonproject
    \\pythonproject\\testvhsn\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-958of2go\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\sfran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distributi
    on option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        running install
        running build
        running config_cc
        unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
        running config_fc
        unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        building library "npymath" sources
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visual studio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
````

```
**What is going on here?**

(I would like to understand how something can fail?)
Whats the problem? please help
```

Comment: The error seems to be clear.. Do you have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater installed on your pc and that environment path set?

Comment: Thank you,
I installed visual c ++ and managed to install yolov3. The problem is that the program keeps giving me error. I am using Pycharm and the code is as follows:

import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from yolov3.utils import detect_image, detect_realtime, detect_video, Load_Yolo_model, detect_video_realtime_mp
from yolov3.configs import *
The error is the same as before:
Unresolved reference 'yolov3'
Unresolved reference 'detect_image'

What is going on now?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There might be a problem in your relative path. Do `print(os.getcwd())` and see where you are located and according to that make sure that your current directory has all the files you are opening in your program. If they are somewhere inside any other directory, just copy those files to the absolute path given by `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Since you are able to install yolov3 on your desktop, this question thread seems to have answered. Please accept the answer I'm posting and consider up-voting

Comment: thanks for the answers,
i managed to install the program after trying to reinstall all packages several times.

Comment: From your comment above, it is clear that after installing visual c++, you were able to install yolov3. You even thanked me for that. Since our effort goes a long way, I asked you to up vote and accept my answer below and close this question. Since for whatever reason, your ego seems to be coming in the way and you don't want to accept the answer. Close the question at least since you have got the answer to your original question. Post your new questions in new threads as we are not here to debug all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**The error seems to be :**

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Do you have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater installed on your pc? Once you have that, please set the environment path and try installing yolov3 again.